# C18 pseudo variables

Tags: c, pic, mplab-c18

I'm looking for a way to make Jalv2-like pseudo variables in C using the C18 compiler. A pseudo variable is something that acts like a variable but actually is a function.

In Jalv2, it's possible to make a pseudo variable like this:

```
function the_var'get() return byte is
    -- some code
end function

procedure the_var'set(byte in value) is
    -- some code
end procedure
```

Now one can read and write to `the_var`, while actually those functions are executed:

```
the_var = 0x40         -- actually executes the_var'set(0x40)
doSomething(the_var)   -- actually executes doSomething(the_var'get)
```

Is there something similar for C?

Comment: It sounds like you are asking for "getters and setters" in C.  No, this is not possible.

Comment: @DietrichEpp is there a workaround?

Comment: Sure, just call the functions explicitly.

Comment: @DietrichEpp not that it looks like the last code example?

Comment: Simply not possible with C.

Comment: @DietrichEpp that's too bad - but can you make that an answer?

Comment: You could do that in C++ and use the IAR C++ compiler for PIC18.

Comment: @angelatlarge assignment operator and implicit conversion operators overloads.

Comment: @zakinster perhaps you could make that an answer? It's a nice alternative

Comment: Dietrich Epp already mentioned it in his answer.

Comment: @zakinster ah yeah I see, never mind

Comment: *"I want feature X, which C doesn't have, but I want to program in C. How do I get feature X in C?"* You don't want to program in C. Use a programming language that has feature X.

Comment: @modifiablelvalue I didn't know yet if C the feature had, so I asked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not possible with C.  It's not even possible with the preprocessor.  The `=` operator always does the exact same thing in C, and there are no ways to customize it.

If you want to do things like that, you'll have to pick a different language.  Like C++, for example, which lets you override `operator =` (for a setter) and `operator int` (for a getter).